# Laravel Vuejs Database check

Tags: mysql, laravel-5, vuejs2

So i have a Laravel project that creates notifications for individuals, and that functionality is within a vue component.  What I'm trying to do is figure out how to have an if/else statement in the component that checks the database to see if the thread being updated is already in the notification log.  And if it is, then it will just updated the updated_at, else it will create a fully new notification.

How do i have vue search the database to see if this is a new notification?

Comment: You make a post request to Laravel to return you the notification log.

Comment: any chance you could show me how the if/else statement would be setup?

Comment: Which if/else statement? Can you add some of your code to the question and describe what you want to accomplish?